# Is there a way to tag stacktraces in logstash/Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elk

I currently am parsing out all my logs to Kibana and have managed to parse out MYSQL methods, Error Logs (INFO, DEBUG) etc but can't for the life of me work out a way to tag stack traces. I need to be able to tag the stacktraces for ease of bug fixing on our nightly run. Would anyone out there have done such a thing or even be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: are you using multiline parsing?

Comment: Hi there. Yes, using multiline parsing. I have the stack traces displaying and everything, I just need a way to tag them as a stack trace if that makes sense?

Comment: Have you tried to find the stacktraces in logstash pipeline (based on some keywords and/or other criteria) and applying tags in same pipeline?

Comment: it sounds like you would need to use some regex, post an example, it would be easier to help you that way